# Quantifying statistical confidence from combining separate tests

Tags: mathematical-statistics

Start off with a population of 200 balls. There are 2 types of tests that can be performed: call it A and B. The results of each test is either true or false. If we randomly select 100 balls and perform only test A on it. Then perform only test B on the remainder. If we get for the first hundred, A is true = 98, A is false = 2. And for the remainder, B is true = 89, B is false = 11. What sort of quantitative statements can I make about the underlying population of 200 balls?

At at even simpler level, if we get A_(true) = 100, B_(true) = 100, chances are 100% that the underlying population is homogeneous (i.e. of a single type). But how does one compute the confidence of this statement? Do we compare it to a population of A_(true) = 50 and B_(true) = 50? But one is then comparing it to a random population. Is a Bayesian approach corresponding to different possibilities, i.e. underlying population of 1 species, 2 species, 2 species, etc., the right way to proceed?

It would be enough if people can share the thinking behind how they would go about working out the above scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I'm very confused by your description, but here are some remarks that will hopefully be helpful.

If you only apply exactly one predicate to each ball, as in the example in your first paragraph, then you have no information about how the predicates are related to each other. You can estimate the univariate distribution of each predicate's values across all the balls, but not the bivariate distribution, which is what you seem interested in.

> At at even simpler level, if we get A_(true) = 100, B_(true) = 100, chances are 100% that the underlying population is homogeneous (i.e. of a single type).

I disagree. It seems quite possible, in your scenario, for any number of the 100 balls not tested with A to be false on A, and similarly for B.

> But how does one compute the confidence of this statement?

Careful with your terminology. "Confidence" is a term from frequentist statistics, where we don't attach probabilities to hypotheses about populations.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comments.

For the first scenario, I see your point regarding the two predicates. If the distribution is continuous, we don't have an idea of what the joint distribution is going to look like without further assumptions.

For the second scenario, I guess I am trying to come up with something similar to a best estimator. Can't I say something like the best estimate for the underlying population is A and B are true? Can I make the statement more rigorous? This "estimator" is on the high side. How would one quantify the bias?

Comment: The distribution of predicate values has to be discrete, not continuous, but you're right, the joint distribution is a mystery without more assumptions or more data.

Comment: "Can't I say something like the best estimate for the underlying population is A and B are true?" — You can certainly make reasonable estimates for the univariate distribution of each. For example, you can treat A as determined by a [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution), where you have a sample of 100 trials, all of which are successes, from a population of 200 trials, and you want a confidence interval for the population number of successful trials.